# I am flipping view but i want 3-D effect in it

Tags: iphone

I am flipping view through this code

- (void) displayView:(UIViewController*)newView {

  ```
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:window cache:YES];
  [window addSubview:newView.view];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
  ```

}

It is good but i am interested in 3-D effects in switching view so what will i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls take a look at 'CATransform3D'. Very easy to use, similar to your flip animation transition.

OR

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=477617

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/21964-3d-cube-view-transition-iphone.html